# git server side hook - only specific branches will be pushed

Tags: git, githooks, repo

i' m very newbie to git hooks. I' d like to make sure that to the repository only branches will be pushed / updated which starts with BT. So no update is possible to master / current branch. How can i achieve that? I guess it should be part of the update script, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a `pre-receive` hook.

```
#!/bin/bash

#sample
z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
while read old new ref;do
    #fail if it's not a branch or the name of the branch does not start with BT
    if [ "${ref:0:13}" != "refs/heads/BT" ];then
        echo "Error: not allowed to update $ref"
        exit 1
    fi

    #deal with other cases if necessary
    #create a ref, branch or tag
    if [ "$old" = "$z40" ];then
        :
    fi

    #delete a ref, branch or tag
    if [ "$new" = "$z40" ];then
        :
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note that this hook will prohibit all operations on all tag names, or Gerrit-style `refs/for/...` names, etc. To allow those, before rejecting branches not starting with `BT`, see if the reference is a branch name (starts with `refs/heads/`).