# Gitlab branch naming guard for comunity edition server

Tags: gitlab, webhooks

Is it possible to validate name of a branch that is trying to be pushed in to repository using GitLab Community Edition and don't allow to push branch with bad naming? I did find solutions that work for starter or enterprise editions, but it's not clear if it's possible to achieve similar result with community edition of the gitlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add a server side hook in Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html).

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201157/git-server-side-hook-only-specific-branches-will-be-pushed) how to specify that only certain branch-names can be pushed.